# Something weird with webElement input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping

I'm recently using javascript to find webelement and interact with websites. My goal is to make the same as selenium "sendkeys" method with javascript. And I found out something weird.

In the Youtube Website, I can use this javascript code to fill automatically the search bar and research it.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "test";
document.getElementById("search-icon-legacy").click();
```

And it works fine! Youtube accept my terms and redirect me to the url

But on some website, it does not work, despite the fact that the keys are really in the right field, and the value seems to be correct in the html, but it does not appear in the search url, therofore, I can't make any search. Here is my code with indeed.com.

```
document.getElementById("text-input-what").value = "test";

document.getElementById("text-input-where").value = "test";

document.getElementsByClassName("yosegi-InlineWhatWhere-primaryButton")[0].click();
```

Is it some security on some website? Did I make a mistake? Is there some other ways to send real keys with javascript? Thank you for any advices

Comment: There are many reasons why this might fail.  Yet, you'd need to provide example code showing how you tried to access a specific website url, the results you expected, and the results you actually got.

Comment: Can you share the HTML for this id `text-input-what`? Is it unique? Can you also put some delay before interaction and see if that helps.

Comment: For my code, I use dart language, and flutter_inappwebview to inject javascript in the page. Example:
print(webViewController?.evaluateJavascript(source: 'document.getElementById("text-input-what").value = "test";'));

Comment: And for the webElement in Indeed, here's the html code: 
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="label-text-input-what" id="text-input-what" name="q" placeholder="Métier, mots-clés ou entreprise" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-owns="text-input-what-suggestion-list" class="icl-TextInput-control icl-TextInput-control--withIconRight" aria-invalid="false">

The tag "value" is changing, but it does not affect the research..

For the delay, I tried but it does not work much. I tried to set the values with javascript, then manually click somewhere, but it still not working..